# How to delete a line of a text file, given the line number using batch (.bat) script?

Tags: batch-processing, batch-file

I want to write a batch script where the user can enter the line number and the script will delete that line of a text file.

Eg: tmp.txt

```
1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc
4. ddd
```

I want when i execute my script and user inputs 3, the tmp.txt to be

```
1. aaa
2. bbb
4. ddd
```

I am trying something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P LINENUMBER=Enter the Line No:

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a IN ('FIND /n /v "" ^< tmp.txt') DO (   
    IF %%a equ %LINENUMBER% (
                  ????????????????????
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you try to write everything but the line you want to delete? IF %%a NEQ %LINENUMBER%

Comment: If you have a Windows version of `sed`, it's trivial: `sed "%LINENUMBER%d" file`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the file directly. You must create a new file with the desired content and then replace the original file with the new file.

You create the new file by redirecting output and ECHOing the desired content. I use `ECHO(%%b` in case %%b is empty because the line was blank. `ECHO %%b` would produce `ECHO is off.` if b is empty. Most people use `ECHO.`, but that can fail under esoteric conditions. `ECHO(` will never fail.

You use MOVE to replace the original file with the new.

You can eliminate the need to check for the number within your FOR /F loop by using FINDSTR after FIND to filter out the unwanted line.

Note that your code, as written so far, will strip any leading `[` and `]` characters from each line. Because the line filter is applied before the FOR iteration, you can improve the situation slightly by setting DELIMS to `]` only.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P LINENUMBER=Enter the Line No:
>tmp.txt.new (
  FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a IN (
    'FIND /n /v "" ^<tmp.txt^|FINDSTR /VLB "[%LINENUMBER%]"'
  ) DO ECHO(%%b
)
>nul MOVE /y tmp.txt.new tmp.txt
```

If any of your original lines already begin with `]` then you can use FINDSTR instead of FIND to introduce the line number. That uses `nn:` format instead of `[nn]`. This solution will strip leading `:` from your lines.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P LINENUMBER=Enter the Line No:
>tmp.txt.new (
  FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a IN (
    'FINDSTR /n "^" tmp.txt^|FINDSTR /VLB "%LINENUMBER%:"'
  ) DO ECHO(%%b
)
>nul MOVE /y tmp.txt.new tmp.txt
```

If your text file contains lines that begin both with `:` and `]` then you can't use FOR /F to parse out the line number. Instead you use search and replace. Delayed expansion is toggled on and off within the loop to protect any `!` that may exist in the file.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
SET /P LINENUMBER=Enter the Line No:
>tmp.txt.new (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (
    'FINDSTR /n "^" tmp.txt ^| FINDSTR /VLB "%LINENUMBER%:"'
  ) DO (
    set "ln=%%a"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
>nul MOVE /y tmp.txt.new tmp.txt
```

Comment: How can `ECHO.` fail? I, being a batch maniac, try random things just for fun and would like to see that happen.

Comment: @JeffreyLin - See this very interesting DOSTips thread on the topic: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=2527

Comment: That's very interesting, but under normal circumstances, I use the period because the formatting shows up somewhat cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

try out this:

```
@echo off & setlocal 
set "InFile=Z:\Text.txt" 
set "OutFile=Z:\Erg.txt" 
set /p LineToDelete=

if exist "%OutFile%" del "%OutFile%" 
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n $ "%InFile%"^|findstr /b "%LineToDelete%:"') do findstr /v /b /c:"%%j" "%InFile%">>"%OutFile%"
```