# Remove selected lines from TXT file with .bat (CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is my TXT file:

```
 Volume in drive N is ABSdrive
 Volume Serial Number is BLA - BLA

 Directory of n:\ggg\gggg\ggg\ggggg

25/10/2016  09:46           138,813 gggggg.csv
               1 File(s)        00000 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  00000000 bytes free
```

What I need is .txt file with ONLY this line

```
25/10/2016  09:46           138,813 gggggg.csv
```

No empty lines on the top or bottom just text file with 1 single line with this information.

Is it any way of make it by using .bat file?

Comment: Hi Dennis, is this a txt file you have to deal with or do you issue the dir cmd  youself? Is there only one file with a predetermined name+ext?

Comment: potentially could be more files, but I will be happy to make it work even for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to parse text:

```dos
@echo off
for /F "usebackq skip=5 delims=" %%E in ("\path\to\your\text\file.txt") do (
    set "LINE=%%E"
    goto :EXIT_FOR
)
:EXIT_FOR
echo %LINE%
```

The `skip=5` option tells `for /F` to ignore the first five lines. The `goto` command leaves the loop after having read the first non-skipped line. So the variable `LINE` will hold the line of interest finally.

Instead of using `goto`, you can also check whether the variable has already been defined, to pick one certain line of text, like this:

```dos
@echo off
set "LINE="
for /F "usebackq skip=5 delims=" %%E in ("\path\to\your\text\file.txt") do (
    if not defined LINE set "LINE=%%E"
)
echo %LINE%
```

---

The text file content looks like the output of a `dir` command (something like `dir "n:\ggg\gggg\ggg\ggggg\gggggg.csv"`). You can parse such command output directly by `for /F` without having to store it into a text file first -- see this:

```dos
@echo off
for /F "skip=5 delims=" %%E in ('dir "n:\ggg\gggg\ggg\ggggg\gggggg.csv"') do (
    set "LINE=%%E"
    goto :EXIT_FOR
)
:EXIT_FOR
echo %LINE%
```

Or:

```dos
@echo off
set "LINE="
for /F "skip=5 delims=" %%E in ('dir "n:\ggg\gggg\ggg\ggggg\gggggg.csv"') do (
    if not defined LINE set "LINE=%%E"
)
echo %LINE%
```

Comment: echo %LINE% > output.txt and your code is perfectly suits.

Answer (score 5):

```
findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]" yourfile.txt > targetfile.txt
```

This getting lines which begins with digit, since that is what you need in your question.

Comment: Bingo! This is the simplest and fastest solution. It can easily be adapted to process the output of a DIR command directly, without the need for a temporary file: `dir /a-d | findstr "^[0-9]" >targefile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the findstr command and the write the output to a new textfile, outfile.txt
Then you can search for that exact string in your file. However this will only write the output to a file if the string searched for matches the line exactly.

```
findstr /x "25/10/2016  09:46           138,813 gggggg.csv" infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

For more information on the findstr command I would recommend opening up a new cmd and typing in

```
findstr /?
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is part of the job, each day there is different file. May be there is a way that will remove specific lines 1-5 and 7-8 and leave only the one I need??

Comment: or copy line 6 to another .txt file.

Comment: Denis you are asking a completely new question, I would recommend marking this question as completed and answered if it has satisified the original question. For your comment look at the following link or create a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736509/how-to-delete-a-line-of-a-text-file-given-the-line-number-using-batch-bat-sc

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop your folder onto this batch file.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcDir=%~1"
If Not Defined SrcDir Set "SrcDir=%CD%"
(For /F EOL^=^ Delims^=^^ %%A In ('Dir/A-D "%SrcDir%"') Do Echo=%%A)>output.txt
```

It should output the output.txt file to that folder. *(if no input folder is given then it should provide the output.txt to the current directory)*.

If you are only wanting to parse the data from a file then adapt it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcFile=%~1"
If Not Defined SrcFile Exit/B
(For /F UseBackQEOL^=^ Delims^=^^ %%A In ("%SrcFile%") Do Echo=%%A)>output.txt
```

Just drag/drop your file onto it or adapt it to replace %~1 with your file path/name on line two.

Comment: tried, not working.

BTW I do not need to make it as drag and drop, this should be as a part of  .bat file.

Comment: It can be easily adapted for the input parameter to be file content, however your output file is the result of a dir command. That dir command should be replaced by what I've posted. _(Also it does work, I use the same function more often than any other)_.