# Delete lines (or tag) from HTML-Files using batch (.bat) script

Tags: html, windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Lets say I have a few HTML-Files starting with similar lines like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

    <TITLE>Some HTML Page</TITLE>
    <H1>something</H1>
    <A>something else</A>
    <A>something else fsomething else></A>
    <A>End of something</A>

    <H2>Beginning of something else
    text text text....</H2>

</HEAD>
```

What I need is to delete some of the code from all those files using the Windows Shell (cmd).
I would prefer a solution which deletes the tag I don't need in this case the `<H2>` Tag which would be unique in all files.

But because as mentioned the files beginnings are similar a (probably easier) solution which allows me to remove a range of lines would also be o.k.
In this case lines **9 to 11**.

What I tried so far for one file and the remove lines method:

```
@Echo OFF

Set /A "BL=9"
Set /A "EL=11"
Set /A "Z=%EL%-%BL%"

(Type "inputFile.html" | MORE +%BL%)>"inputFile.html"
```

I would probably need the Opposite function call of `MORE` so i could first write everything before line 9 into the file and in a second step append everything after line 11 with the `MORE` command and `>>`.

I tried to extend this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737334/4543887
to my needs, but well my Command line skills are pretty basic.

I know it would be easy using for example `sed`, but Im restricted to `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about some of the tag indents being changed, you could use DOM methods in JScript.  It's generally better to objectify and parse structured markup data such as HTML, XML, JSON, etc, than to hack and scrape as flat text anyway. Save this with a .bat extension and salt to taste.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "in=test.html"

rem // run JScript hybrid code, passing the HTML content via stdin
<"%in%" cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"

rem // Exit script.  You're done.  w00p w00p!
goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    stdin = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(0).ReadAll(),
    trash = {};

// force loading IE11 engine then clear
DOM.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11" />');
DOM.close();

// load HTML into the IE11 engine and manipulate
DOM.write(stdin);
trash = DOM.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
trash.parentNode.removeChild(trash);

// output modified HTML
WSH.Echo(DOM.documentElement.outerHTML);
DOM.close();
```

The `htmlfile` COM object isn't very well documented on Microsoft's website.  But you can see all its properties and methods by doing

```js
powershell "new-object -COM htmlfile | gm | more"
```